# ASP .NET Core, SignalR (WebSocket) not connect with AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

In my sample project, I have problem with SignalR and WebSocket Trasport Protocol.
When I try to connect with Hub under AuthorizeAttribute, the response is:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44341/chat/negotiate text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Policy execution successful.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: Successfully validated the token.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization was successful.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 37.4131ms 200 application/json
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44341/chat?id=bSfQQIMQk3-AWf7jTVfwsw&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiYW5kcmVhLnRvc2F0byIsImV4cCI6MTUzNDQ5OTI5NywiaXNzIjoiY2xvdWRnZW4uY29kZWdlbi5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJjbG91ZGdlbi5jb2RlZ2VuLmNvbSJ9.47NxR5bGKWqPyPDi7Yz_PaYJTHKUJcJyRWfftxJRBq4
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Policy execution successful.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.

Client, after WebSocket, failed with Server Sent Events. With Long-polling all work fine.

My client:

```
      this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(environment.baseHubs + '/chat', {
        accessTokenFactory: () => token,
        logger: LogLevel.Trace
      })
      // .withHubProtocol(new JsonHubProtocol())
      .withHubProtocol(new MessagePackHubProtocol())
      .build();


  this.connection.start()
                 .catch(this.errorConnection.bind(this))
                 .then(x => {
                    this.connection.invoke('GetUserContext').then(this.getUserContext.bind(this));
                  });
```

[Complete Code](https://github.com/andreatosato/RealTime/blob/master/ChatPWA/chat-app/src/app/services/chatHub.service.ts#L29-L42)

My Server code:

```
         services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Authentication:Audiance"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Authentication:SecurityKey"]))
                };
            });
```

[Complete Code](https://github.com/andreatosato/RealTime/blob/0803bf9669392f5035166b4062d7bea3434caa5a/ChatPWA/ChatApp.Backend/ChatApp.Backend/Startup.cs#L26-L39)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolution:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {   
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Authentication:Audiance"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Authentication:SecurityKey"]))
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```